# is there a function to insert axis labels to a plot with one variable in R?

Tags: r, plot

I need to insert axis values to a plot with just one variable in R
I can't use plot(date1, y) because I need to add lines with different length so I need to know if there is any way to make this work and label the x-axis by using just one variable inside the plot function

```
a <- rnorm(177); b <- rnorm(177)
c <- data.frame(a,b)
date1 <- seq(as.Date("2020-02-22"), as.Date("2020-09-08"), by="1 day") #these are 200 days
y <- rnorm(200)
plot(y, xaxt = "n") #I delete the default labels to label the x-axis by date
axis.Date(1, at=seq(min(date1), max(date1), by="1 day"), format="%Y-%m-%d") #This do not show anything
lines(c$a,c$b) #With this code the lines are draw

#if I use this code axis.Date work bur lines do not 
plot(date1, y, xaxt = "n")
axis.Date(1, at=seq(min(date1), max(date1), by="1 day"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
lines(c$a,c$b)
```

Comment: I'm confused as to why you can't do `plot(date1, y, xaxt = "n")`. This doesn't draw any lines, and if you do this, then your `axis.Date` will work

Comment: I also have a data frame of different length `a <- rnorm(20); b <- rnorm(20); c <- data.frame(a,b); plot(y, xaxt="n"); lines(c$a,c$b)` this code allow to plot the line but 
`axis.Date` do not work. If I plot as you said `lines(c$a,c$b)`doesn't draw any line

Comment: So your `y` values correspond to dates between 2020-02-22 and 2020-09-08. So when you draw lines from a to b, those numbers are like 0.51 to -0.92. What date values are those numbers meant to correspond to? What should they match up to on the x-axis? `plot(y, xaxt = "n")` is basically the same as `plot(seq_along(y), y, xaxt = "n")` so all your dates are turned into numbers 1,2,3 etc. which is unlikely to be what you want

Comment: The Data frame represents the actual data, and `y` is the predicted line. I am plotting a logistic and exponential model to show the predicted values of the graph against the actual values to see the direction it would take. So I have one more line to plot. I couldn't plot the actual data with the x-axes because is shorter than the predicted values and do not work.